# iOS: Aligning two UILabels (left/right) and connecting with dots?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uilabel

[image]

The above image was taken from an Android app. I am looking to do the same thing on iOS. I know how to do it using a background image for the dots, but it doesn't look like the Android developer used an image for the dots. Anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this without any code. Just use two labels with their baselines aligned, and with a horizontal spacing constraint of 0. The left label would have its text left aligned with say 10 dots added to the end of the string, and the line break mode set to "clips". The right label would also be left aligned, so its text would always be right up against the dots.

**After Edit:** I couldn't get this to work in IB. It may be possible in code using constraints, but I haven't tried that. It seems like you should be able to do it with 3 labels, with the two outside ones pinned to the edges of the view, and a flexible label in the middle whose text would be dots.

Comment: This is a good solution, even i thought this one. But I failed to think "what if both textboxes' text are too long and will meet at centre like crashed"

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, yeah, I think you might be right. I'm still trying to see if I can make this work for different length numbers with just constraints in IB.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: So, I ended up using two labels. Using sizeWithFont to size and position the right label, and having the left label fill the rest of the space, while clipping the text. Worked great. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the way to do it with content hugging/compression resistance.
Here is the interface builder solution:
[image: UILabel filled with dots]

Left label has a phrase and lots of dots with line breaking = truncate tail. Content hugging/compression resistance do the rest of job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSAttributedString` to format in  that way.

Use two colors in two ranges, even bold font for 2nd part.

And calculate the total width (length of your text) and fill dots (.) in between those.

An idea to fill dots:

lets say you have 30 characters space.

str1 contains 10, str2 contains 6, then use 30-(10+6) then in a loop

```
for(30-(10+6) times) {
    [mainString appendString:@"."]
}
```

Comment: How would you "fill dots" in between?

Comment: lets say you have 30 characters space. str1 contains 10, str2 contains 6, then use 30-(10+6) and in a loop for(14 times)[mainString appendString:@"."]

Comment: @AnoopVaidya because of the variable width of all letters (unless you use monospaced letters lol) this won't work as there will be variable sized gaps in there at some point between the last . and the last word.